# Unable to compile JSP, Exception: org.apache.jasper.JasperException

Tags: jsp

I am getting the below error because of line `System.out.println(sendURL.substring(0, sendURL.lastIndexOf("/")));` sendURL is not null, it has value in it. Anyone please help me to reslve this. Thanks in advance!

**Message**

> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**Exception**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/authenticate.jsp at line 47

44:     config = getServletConfig(); 
45:     String localStoreurl=application.getInitParameter("localstorefile"); 
46:     String domain=application.getInitParameter("domain");
47:     System.out.println(sendURL.substring(0, sendURL.lastIndexOf("/")));
48: %>
49: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
50:     <head>


Stacktrace:     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:519)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:428)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 root cause java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.jsp.authenticate_jsp._jspService(authenticate_jsp.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.30 logs.
```

Apache Tomcat/6.0.30

Comment: why don't you post here the full scriptlet? is more or less clear that the error is with the `sendURL` variable but if we don't see how do you declare/initialize it, we can't provide help

Answer (score 0):

I think it is throwing [IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html), it is thrown if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex. Read it's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

In your case  beginIndex will be larger than endIndex, if  string doesn't contain any ' **/** '.

You should check for these conditions before calling subString method.

Answer (score 0):

Please check `sendURL` variable may be it's value null.